# write or replace data in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

Using this code I have write/replace data in an excel file. But now i need to do the same thing for csv file. Can someone help me with that?

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('2.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:  
    fm_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Raw Data1')
```

Comment: use [df.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

ExcelWriter are used to write to excel files. If you are using pandas dataframes you can use to_csv instead.

`df.to_csv('csvfilename.csv')`

Here is is link to the relevant documentation for to_csv https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

If you are not using pandas, take a look at the csv package: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas' [`to_csv()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv('2.csv)
```